# Non-isomorphic $k[G]$-modules

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $k$ a field.

Suppose that $W_1,W_2$ are $k[G]$-modules (so $G$-representations over the field $k$) such that the induced map $G\to \text{End}_k(W_1)\times\text{End}_k(W_2)$ is surjective.  I am reading that this implies $W_1$ cannot be isomorphic to $W_2$ as a $k[G]$-module, but I don't see why this is, can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: The induced map is probably meant to begin in $k\left[G\right]$. And you probably want to require $W_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: Look for an element of $k\left[G\right]$ that acts on $W_1$ as identity and on $W_2$ as $0$. Such an element exists, due to the surjectivity assumption.

Comment: Yes, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are nonzero.

Comment: Ah.  Of course.  Thanks!!!